# SSRS: How to assign multiple users a role to a report quickly?

Tags: reporting-services

In SSRS, assigning roles to multiple users of a report is straightforward.

But how about the other way round: assign roles of a single user to multiple reports?

In my case I need to assign a browser role of an AD group to over 100 reports which scatters in different folders. Grouping these reports to a new folder and then assign a user to it is not an option here.

I heard that I could carry out this by using SQL... Can anyone here give me advices? Thanks a lot in advance..

Comment: In the ReportServer database, look at the following tables `Catalog`, `Users`, `Roles`, `Policies`, `PolicyUserRole`.

Comment: @AlanSchofield I read from the following that even though I have at least WRITE permissions of the 5 system tables you have listed, I still cannot use T-SQL to add new user assignments as I wanted. I could only add or modify or delete the Roles table via T-SQL. Is that true? If yes, can I use PowerShell to do the job? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure tbh. I htought I had done something similar years ago but could not find any scripts. I think I had to use the SP's in the ReportServer database to create users, Roles etc, but it wasn't simple. I think I took backups of the tables, added a single user, and then compared to the backup to see what had changed. Then wrote a script to replicate that across all users.