# Basic question about using PowerShell to modify user assignments in SSRS

Tags: powershell, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have somple experience in PowerShell but I don't have experience in using it to automate SQL Server Reporting Service. Basically I want to assign a user a role to a particular report object in SSRS. I have found the following codes in

[SSRS: How to assign multiple users a role to a report quickly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74690096/ssrs-how-to-assign-multiple-users-a-role-to-a-report-quickly)

It seems a good start for creating my script.

```
function Add-SSRSUserRole
(   
    [string]$reportServerUrl,[string]$userGroup,[string]$requiredRole,[string]$folder,[bool]$inheritFromParent
)
{
    #Ensure we stop on errors
    $ErrorActionPreference = "Stop";
    #Connect to the SSRS webservice 
    $ssrs = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri "$reportServerUrl" -UseDefaultCredential;
    $namespace = $ssrs.GetType().Namespace;
    $changesMade = $false;

    #Look for a matching policy     
    $policies = $ssrs.GetPolicies($folder, [ref]$inheritFromParent);
    if ($policies.GroupUserName -contains $userGroup)
    {
        Write-Host "User/Group already exists. Using existing policy.";
        $policy = $policies | where {$_.GroupUserName -eq $userGroup} | Select -First 1 ;
    }
    else
    {
        #A policy for the User/Group needs to be created
        Write-Host "User/Group was not found. Creating new policy.";
        $policy = New-Object -TypeName ($namespace + '.Policy');
        $policy.GroupUserName = $userGroup;
        $policy.Roles = @();
        $policies += $policy;
        $changesMade = $true;
    }

    #Now we have the policy, look for a matching role
    $roles = $policy.Roles;
    if (($roles.Name -contains $requiredRole) -eq $false)
    {
        #A role for the policy needs to added
        Write-Host "Policy doesn't contain specified role. Adding.";
        $role = New-Object -TypeName ($namespace + '.Role');
        $role.Name = $requiredRole;
        $policy.Roles += $role;
        $changesMade = $true;
    }
    else 
    {
        Write-Host "Policy already contains specified role. No changes required.";
    }

    #If changes were made...
    if ($changesMade)
    {
        #...save them to SSRS
        Write-Host "Saving changes to SSRS.";
        $ssrs.SetPolicies($folder, $policies);
    }
    Write-Host "Complete.";
}

[string]$url = "http://localhost/ReportServer/ReportService2006.asmx?wsdl";
Add-SSRSUserRole $url "Everyone" "Browser" "/MyReportFolder" $true;
Add-SSRSUserRole $url "Domain\User" "Browser" "/MyReportFolder" $true;
```

Now I have two elementary questions:

1. Do I need any SSRS modules to be installed in my PowerShell in order to run the above script?
2. The sample code above assign a permission to a folder. What changes are required if I want to assign permissions to a *report object* directly instead?

Thanks for your response in advance,

Comment: SSRS is HTML format.  So you need to send a HTTP request to the SSRS server.  So sending to SSRS is the same as sending any HTTP Request.  The HTTP request can use Windows Authentication which take the client credentials and passes them to the server.  So you can simply change permissions in the SSRS report to work with any set of client credentials.  Your powershell script is sending an HTTP Request and you will get back an HTTP Response.  You can test the SSRS credentials by using any browser an connecting to the SSRS URL.

Comment: @jdweng Thanks for your response. Do you mean that no additional additional modules, like the ReportingServicesTools, need to be installed in PowerShell to run the above script succuessfully?

Comment: ReportingServicesTools are tools to manage the SSRS and not needed to run a RDLC report.  SSRS runs scripts which are RDLC (HTML Format) that does the queries.  You run the queries with a HTTP Request.  See following for a list of functions that are part of ReportingServicesTools : https://github.com/microsoft/ReportingServicesTools?force_isolation=true

Comment: @jdweng Thanks for your explanation, which has given me a good start.